# How to append values to keys in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a sample dictionary:

```
f = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"}
```

How do I append a value to all of them to make it look like:

```
f = {"1":"one", "2":"two", "3":three", "4":"four", "5":"five", "6","six:, "7":"seven", "8":"eight"}
```

Comment: Your first example is not a dictionary, it is a set - you can't add values. but you can construct a new dictionary from your set. Your question falls down somewhat because it is unclear where you want to get the values from, but a dictionary comprehension is probably what you want, i.e: `{key: generate_value(key) for key in f}`.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1):

This sample is a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) not a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

```
f = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"}
```

Dictionaries need a value for corresponding keys. And technically you don't 'append' a value to a key, that word is reserved for other data structures where elements can be inserted from the end, but to assign a value to a key you can do:

```
f = dict()
f['1'] = 'one'
```

You can also assign lists/sets to keys in a dictionary, and *append* values to those lists:

```
z = list()
f = dict()
f['1'] = z
f['1'].append('one')
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement your example, this should do the trick:

```
import inflect

f = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"}

engine = inflect.engine()
f = {k: engine.number_to_words(int(k)) for k in f}
```

Note that dictionaries are not ordered so the result is:

```
{'4': 'four',
 '6': 'six',
 '8': 'eight',
 '1': 'one',
 '5': 'five',
 '3': 'three',
 '2': 'two',
 '7': 'seven'}
```

Comment: OP would need to install inflect for this. I can see why you included this though, it does look like OP wants to convert the digit keys to their word counterpart, however, perhaps installing the inflect library just for that task is a bit too much?

Comment: Since Python 3.7, `dict`s do actually maintain insertion order. The reason the order is different here (assuming you are using a modern Python version) is actually because the source set doesn't maintain order.